# Report of Uptime for Azure Services

Tags: azure, sla

Are you aware of any resource that monitors the uptime of Azure services?

I've been asked to demonstrate that Microsoft meets their stated SLA, specifically for Azure Active Directory Basic or Premium.

Microsoft provides this uptime information for Office 365 here, but this figure doesn’t list metrics for Azure:

https://products.office.com/en-us/business/office-365-trust-center-operations

The best I’ve been able to find with regard to Azure is a feedback post from 2014 here:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/231545-diagnostics-and-monitoring/suggestions/6176762-adding-reports-like-sla-uptime-reports-for-virtua

Thanks for your time!

Greg

Answer (score 1):

Yes and No. For monitoring your specific resources, you can use Azure Monitor (and log analytics if you want more aggregation), so long as you collect the right metrics you can see the uptime for your services.

That said, Azure AD is not one of the services that work with Azure monitor, unfortunately. If you have an app that relies on Azure AD you could use App Insights to collect login error data and use that as a metric.

There isn't really a global SLA metric. You can use Azure Service Health to look at incidents and issue that have occurred in the past, but it won't give you a metric.